# Convert Code PHP Array To JSP

Tags: php, jsp

i want create array in JSP

```
<?php
$lang = array();
$lang['PAGE_TITLE'] = 'My website page title';
$lang['HEADER_TITLE'] = 'My website header title';
$lang['SITE_NAME'] = 'My Website';
$lang['SLOGAN'] = 'My slogan here';
$lang['HEADING'] = 'My Heading';
echo $lang['SITE_NAME']; // print words "My Website"
?>
```

i try in JSP like this.

```
<%
String[] lang;
lang["PAGE_TITLE"] = "My website page title";
lang["HEADER_TITLE"] = "My website header title";
lang["SITE_NAME"] = "My Website";
lang["SLOGAN"] = "My slogan here";
lang["HEADING"] = "My Heading";
out.println(lang["SITE_NAME"]);  // print words "My Website"
%>
```

this error, cannot convert int to string
Help me thank's, i want call Array JSP like code Array in PHP

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `Map<String,String>` same as:

```
Map<String, String> lang = new HashMap<String, String>();
lang.put("PAGE_TITLE", "My website page title");
lang.put("HEADER_TITLE","My website header title");
lang.put("SITE_NAME","My Website");
lang.put("SLOGAN", "My slogan here");
lang.put("HEADING","My Heading");
out.println(lang.get("SITE_NAME"));
```

Comment: An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file: learning.jsp
Map cannot be resolved to a type
1: 
2: <%
3: Map<String, String> lang = new HashMap<String, String>();
4: lang.put("PAGE_TITLE", "My website page title");
5: lang.put("HEADER_TITLE","My website header title");
6: lang.put("SITE_NAME","My Website");

Comment: You just need to import java.util.*; for this